# Handle error message from the cat command

Tags: bash, shell, sh, databricks, databricks-notebook

I am using Databricks Notebook to execute Shell script using the `%sh` and I want to capture error message into `err` variable and then print the error message if the `cat` command fails (for eg, purposefully fail if the `header_file` directory doesn't exist). In the below code, if the `cat` command fails, it is coming inside the `if` statement and printing the error code correctly, but it is not showing the error from the `err` variable. The error message is showing as `Error msg :`  and not showing why `cat` command failed.

```
err=$(cat /dbfs/mnt/devl/header_file/*.csv /dbfs/mnt/devl/data_files/*.csv > /dbfs/mnt/devl/output.txt 2>&1)
RC=$?
if [ $RC -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Error code : $RC"
  echo "Error msg : $err"
fi
```

I checked if the issue is with the `cat` command and tried to replicate using `ls` command. In `ls` command, it is displaying the error message correctly as `Error msg : ls: cannot access '/dbfs/mnt/devl/header_file/*.csv': No such file or directory`. Is this due to some limitation with the `cat` command?

```
err=$(ls /dbfs/mnt/devl/header_file/*.csv 2>&1)
RC=$?
if [ $RC -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Error code : $RC"
  echo "Error msg : $err"
fi
```

**Note** :
My question is not related how to handle file/folder not found. The intention of this question is to display the actual error message that says why `cat` command failed for any kind of failure from the `cat` command.

Comment: I believe it would be due to the fact that you have the stderr to stdout redirection after/alongside the stdout to file redirection. But I'm not sure

Comment: Apparently what you did here is a Bash manual example for redirecting both stdout and stderr to a file. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirecting-Standard-Output-and-Standard-Error You should thus find the not found error in the destination file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve the issue by changing the places of `STDOUT` and `STDERR` redirects:

```
err=$(cat /dbfs/mnt/devl/header_file/*.csv /dbfs/mnt/devl/data_files/*.csv 2>&1 > /dbfs/mnt/devl/output.txt)
```

This will send the `STDERR` to the original `STDOUT` handler (in your case this is a `err` variable) and redirect the original `STDOUT` handler to file.

Comment: Pretty simple solution. This worked. Just eager to know, is the answer provided by KamilCuk here works the same way or is there any advantages/drawbacks on KamilCuk's approach?

Comment: @SarathSubramanian, the answer of KamilCuk use different approach by grouping the `cat` and use redirect to STDERR of the entire command. WHich work, but it is a bit more complicated :)

Comment: Thanks Romeo for the quick response. Really appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

`>` is handled by shell, not by `cat`. `cat` is not printing any messages. Add a command block for the inner shell to have the redirection.

```
err=$(
    {
        cat \
            /dbfs/mnt/devl/header_file/*.csv \
            /dbfs/mnt/devl/data_files/*.csv \
            > /dbfs/mnt/devl/output.txt
    } 2>&1
)
RC=$?
if ((!RC)); then
  echo "Error code : $RC"
  echo "Error msg : $err"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The redirection order is tricky. Like h0tw1r3 says here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/298528/96266 and links https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html which says:

> Note that the order of redirections is significant. For example, the command
>
> ```bash
> ls > dirlist 2>&1
> ```
>
> directs both standard output (file descriptor 1) and standard error (file descriptor 2) to the file dirlist, while the command
>
> ```bash
> ls 2>&1 > dirlist
> ```
>
> directs only the standard output to file dirlist, because the standard error was made a copy of the standard output before the standard output was redirected to dirlist.

Your question is the opposite of that question.

```
$ ls a b ga
ls: nie ma dostępu do 'a': No such file or directory
ls: nie ma dostępu do 'b': No such file or directory
ga:
$ ls a b ga 2>&1 > g | wc
      2      22     108
$ cat g
ga:
```